# How to check tabController for null?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can you please tell me how can I check tabController for null:

```js
final CupertinoTabController? tabController = CupertinoTabController(initialIndex: 0);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to see if tabController is not null? If so, just write ```if (tabController != null) {//your logic here}```

Answer (score 0):

A simple conditional check would do it for you

```dart
if (tabController != null) {
 // code for tabController is not null
} 
else {
 // code for tabController is null
}
```

A ternary operator can be used too

```dart
(tabController != null) ? codeForNotNull : codeForNull
```

Reference: [official docs](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#null-aware-operators)